# xlwings quickstart python script not working

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I'm try to run a python script using `VBA` and found `Xlwings` to be quite helpful as described in various blog posts. 
I installed xlwings using my terminal and the excel add-in and enabled the xlwings button in the VPA-tool section.

I have created a project using the following line in my terminal window:

```
xlwings quickstart hallo_welt
```

Thus, a python script and a xslm file are created in the respective folder "hallo_welt". Both are named the same.
If I try to click on the "Run Main" button it is not running, but returning the following

```
error:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hallo_welt'
```

[See also screenshot attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDLlB.png)

The python code looks like this:

```
import xlwings as xw


def main():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    sheet = wb.sheets[0]
    if sheet["A1"].value == "Hello xlwings!":
        sheet["A1"].value = "Bye xlwings!"
    else:
        sheet["A1"].value = "Hello xlwings!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xw.Book("hallo_welt.xlsm").set_mock_caller()
    main()
```

And thus, it should return "Hello xlwings!" in cell A1 the first time I click on "Run Main".

Comment: Did you forget to include the screenshots?

Comment: Now it should be included! :) 
Thanks!

Comment: It's case sensitive so make sure the case is the same as shown in the error. `No module named 'hallo_welt'` the file it's looking for, `'hallo_welt.py'` should be all lower case letters.

Comment: my file ist named 'hallo_welt.py' so cases should not be an issue. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: Agreed it should not be an issue as running the command will produce both files in the same case (lower). The error message means either the python file is not in the same directory as the xlsm file or it has a different name. These two reasons are unlikely from your description. There is one other possible, tho again unlikely, reason and that is the python file must be the same case as the xlsm file so if for example `'hallo_welt.py'` was inadvertantly changed to `'Hallo_welt.py'` you'd get that error also. Beyond that I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Hm...weird, as both files have the same name and are in the same folder..I will try to reinstall xlwings, maybe that will help..But thanks for your help @moken. :)